# How to increase number of TextView over time ?

Tags: android

I want users to input from `EditText` and whatever he enter in the `EditText` he pressed a submit button (go to the list of his inputs), it is going to be printed in `TextView` but If I want to have a long list of `Textview` (show a long list of his history of inputs)... what can I do to have the number of `TextView` to grow like a list as the user submit more `EditText` ?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: do u want to show the listview with multitext!! for every list item????

Answer (score 0):

You can create TextView dynamically inside java class and then add in your parent view.

Use something like below:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then inside java class

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info)


    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
    valueTV.setId(5);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    linearLayout.addView(valueTV);
```

Comment: At runtime create new textview and add in LinearLayout